# color rojo en los nombres de las clases

Tags: intellij-idea

espero que esteis todo bien, soy nueva en este mundo y esto frustrada, ya que estoy intentando aprender un lenguaje nuevo, mi problema es la siguiente, en primer lugar estaba trabajando en un portatil y ahora he cambiado de dispositivo y he importado todos mis proyectos, las clases que hice al principio son de colores blanco, pero los que estoy haciendo nuevos aparecen en color rojo,no se donde esta el fallo, espero con ansias vuentra ayuda ya que no la he encontrado en ninguna parte, gracias de ante mano[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Según [la documentación](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/file-status-highlights.html#editor), el color rojo es significa **Unversioned**. Se debe a que estás utilizando control de versiones pero el archivo no tiene seguimiento. Si escribes `git status`, lo verás en la lista titulada **Untracked files**.

[image: Captura documentación]

Comment: si estoy unida a gitHub, no encuentro el apartado de git status?

Comment: `git status` es un comando de git. Debes ejecutarlo en la carpeta del proyecto, en tu computadora.